# Empty array values in array of objects using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below.is there any way or one line code to empty all values inside array without foreach loop.

```json
$array=json_decode('{
  "client": "4",
  "gateWay": "1",
  "store": "store.shop.com",
  "valid": "true",
  "po": 34535,
  "additionalPO": 23423,
  "customerNotes": "",
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "item": "123",
      "quantity": 10,
      "supplierLotNo": "",
      "customsValue": "",
      "customsDescription": "",
      "hsCode": ""
    },
    {
      "item": "345",
      "quantity": 50
    }
  ],
  "shippingInfos": [
    {
      "address": {
        "city": "Chennai",
        "country": "India",
        "postalCode": "86715",
        "state": "TN",
        "streetAddress1": "6971 North Street",
        "streetAddress2": null
      },
      "contact": {
        "company": null,
        "email": "info@store.com",
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "phoneNo": null
      },
      "ServiceId": "3",
      "thirdPartyAccountNo": "",
      "signatureConfirmation": false,
      "saturdayDelivery": false
    }
  ]
}',true);
```

The expected output should be I need empty string for string values,0 for integer values.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _...empty all values inside array..._ Can you show us the expected output?`

Comment: Arrays begin with `[`. Your string begins with an object.

Comment: BTW, that's not an array, that's JSON serialized object, did you decoded it already to PHP's array?

Comment: You can use `array_map()` instead of a `foreach()`. Btw, what does speak against foreach?

Comment: @biesior yes I am decoding it using json_decode.

Comment: Why don't you show us that? Posting just some portion of input data doesn't allow to guess what did you try, please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and pretend you're talking to a busy colleague...

Comment: @biesior sorry for taking your time. I have updated my question.

Comment: Although don't know your requirements I'd iterate and reset values in each node checking the type by `is_array()`, `is_int()`, `is_string()` (or other is_something()`) functions. For sure there's no one-liner for that and it depends on your array's structure. On the other hand, if it is a static structure, you can replace it completely with a blank array instead of purging each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `array_walk`, assuming boolean is set to be `NULL`, here is the code.

---

### Code

```php
<?php

$array=json_decode('{
  "client": "4",
  "gateWay": "1",
  "store": "store.shop.com",
  "valid": "true",
  "po": 34535,
  "additionalPO": 23423,
  "customerNotes": "",
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "item": "123",
      "quantity": 10,
      "supplierLotNo": "",
      "customsValue": "",
      "customsDescription": "",
      "hsCode": ""
    },
    {
      "item": "345",
      "quantity": 50
    }
  ],
  "shippingInfos": [
    {
      "address": {
        "city": "Chennai",
        "country": "India",
        "postalCode": "86715",
        "state": "TN",
        "streetAddress1": "6971 North Street",
        "streetAddress2": null
      },
      "contact": {
        "company": null,
        "email": "info@store.com",
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "phoneNo": null
      },
      "ServiceId": "3",
      "thirdPartyAccountNo": "",
      "signatureConfirmation": false,
      "saturdayDelivery": false
    }
  ]
}',true);


($fx = function (&$in) use (&$fx) { is_array($in) ? array_walk($in, $fx) : ($in = is_string($in) ? "" : (is_int($in) ? 0 : NULL));})($array);

var_dump($array);
```

---

## Output

```
array(9) {
  ["client"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["gateWay"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["store"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["valid"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["po"]=>
  int(0)
  ["additionalPO"]=>
  int(0)
  ["customerNotes"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["orderItems"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["item"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(0)
      ["supplierLotNo"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customsValue"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customsDescription"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["hsCode"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["item"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  ["shippingInfos"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["address"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["city"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["country"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["postalCode"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["state"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["streetAddress1"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["streetAddress2"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["contact"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["company"]=>
        NULL
        ["email"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["firstName"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["lastName"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["phoneNo"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["ServiceId"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["thirdPartyAccountNo"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["signatureConfirmation"]=>
      NULL
      ["saturdayDelivery"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for saving my time.It works perfect.I accepted your answer.